How can ASP.NET Core Identity seed data be added using the UseSeeding in EF Core 9?
I upgraded my project from .NET 8 to .NET 9. However, I got an error when I migrated the database. There is a discussion related to this problem on GitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/35110.
This is my code which is not working for EF Core 9:
var seedUser = new MyUser
    {
        Id = "ID",
        UserName = "username",
        NormalizedUserName = "username".ToUpper(),
        EmailConfirmed = true,
        Email = email,
        NormalizedEmail = email.ToUpper(),
        LockoutEnabled = false
    };

var ph = new PasswordHasher<MyUser>();
seedUser.PasswordHash = ph.HashPassword(seedUser, "password123");

modelBuilder.Entity<MyUser>().HasData(seedUser);

It seems we should not use any dynamic value when using HasData method to add seed data in EF Core 9, like Guid.NewGuid() or HashPassword(). Microsoft also recommends users use the new method UseSeeding to add seed data if users want to add any seed data of ASP.NET Core Identity roles and users.
So, my question is, how do I get the UserManager or RoleManager services? I tried the below code, but it didn't work for me.
services.AddDbContext<DbContext>((sp, options) =>
        {            
            var userManager = sp.GetRequiredService<UserManager<MyUser>>();

            options.UseNpgsql(connectionString)
              .UseAsyncSeeding((context, _, cancellationToken) => Seeding(context, userManager, cancellationToken));
        });


Did you add Identity to DI before DbContext?

@Parsa99 Yes, I believe I've added Identity before it.

Try to get the UserManager (and the rest of the services) from inside the .UseAsyncSeeding method like this:
.UseAsyncSeeding(async (context, storeOperationPerformed, ct) =>
{
    var userManager = context.GetService<UserManager<MyUser>>();
});

You should also add this using:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;

, in order to be able to call GetService method from DbContext.
